# sender currentTitle not recognized in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am doing something as simple as get the current title of an UIButton

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSString *someString = [sender currentTitle];
}
```

For some reason Xcode confuses `sender` with `self` because the complete options only retunrns methods that belongs to "self". No matter whatever I do, I get the same

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *someString = [btn currentTitle];
}
```

Xcode crashes in `NSString` line with "unrecognized selector sent to btn". I can copy working code from another project and the same happens. What could be wrong?

**SOLUTION**

Resarted XCode and it worked fine o.O

Comment: Are you sure `sender` is, in fact, a `UIButton`? Can you paste the entire error verbatim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Resarted XCode and it worked fine o.O

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Xcode is confusing `sender` with `self`, what's happening is that Xcode knows nothing about `sender`, since it was declared as `id`, which means Xcode only knows it's an object.

The suggestions you are getting in Xcode are probably just methods every object has.

You have to make sure that `sender` is what you expect, try doing this and checking if it's actually a button or something else:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Sender: %@", sender);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason for "unrecognized selector sent to btn" is when you call a method which was not actually written. Or you might be called

```
[self buttonPressed];
```

instead of

```
[self buttonPressed:];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your calling the 'id' not the button its self. Replace the 'id' with 'UIButton' like so...

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSString *someString = sender.currentTitle;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is wrong syntax

It is

```
 sender.currentTitle;
```

OR

```
btn.currentTitle;
```

currentTitle is a property and there is no function called currentTitle and hence you get the error **"unrecognized selector sent to btn".**